# Where can I find long questlines?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Apart from main quest and Winterhold/Thieves guild, where can I find other long questlines (i.e. not take book *x* or kill *y* and come back for reward)?

Answer (score 4):

- [The Bard's College](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Bards_College_%28Faction%29)
- [The Companions](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/The_Companions)
- [The Dark Brotherhood](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/The_Dark_Brotherhood_%28Skyrim%29)

Those are the ones that I know of.

Comment: don't forget the mage quest chain

Comment: Which one? College of Winterhold?

Comment: Yeah I'd say the College of Winterhold was pretty long.

Comment: The asker pretty much excluded Winterhold up there, no?

Answer (score 0):

I am having a lot of fun doing the Companions quest chain.  They are located in Whiterun on the east side. They are inside a large house in the court yard where the tree is in the center.  It is up a small set of steps.  Its called Jorrvaskr.  I wont spoil anything for you.  Have fun with them.  Lots of great story telling there.

Answer (score -2):

to be honest I say the most fun long questline was the companions and the dark brotherhood combined. and the main dragonborn was the best afterall